# Should I check for UUID collisions?

Tags: uuid

I'm creating a program where I heavily use UUIDs to identify things like users and groups. Given the extremely low chance of a UUID already being taken, should I worry about the possibility of a collision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That very much depends on A) your requirements B) the underlying implementation and "real" chances of your "library" coming up with a duplicated UUID.

Example: I am working on a software stack were our customers are running with several "worker machines" W1, W2, ... to Wn. And one or more "manager machines" M1, M2.

Those workers create "objects" identified by a UUID. We fully trust the "standard" libraries to create those UUIDs there - thus: no additional checking.

On the other hand, those manager instances see all workers; and to avoid that conflicts on their level, we make sure that each worker has a UUID; and that UUID is factored into the UUIDs generated on the worker machines.

In other words: if your UUIDs are generated and used on one system; then there is (not much) reason to be worried. But when your ids need to be unique within a larger context, you could look into such kind of precautions.

Comment: Aren't those precautions already built into GUIDs - version 1 GUIDs use the machine's MAC address so you should not get the same GUID from different worker machines.

Comment: @PeteKirkham What about 'chinese' clones of network adapters, that has same MAC's, but are on different subnetworks? :)